# Is there a "simple" factoring of Costa's minimal surface piercing a compact surface?

Tags: general-topology, riemannian-geometry, minimal-surfaces

I've only just heard of [Costa's minimal surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Costa%27s_minimal_surface). I'm interested in the fact that it may be formed by puncturing a compact surface.

Another, more simple, minimal surface is the [Catenoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenoid). This also may be formed by puncturing a compact surface. In three dimensions this is just a "handle" added to the 3-sphere, and has the topology $$S^{2}\times S^{1}$$

Can the topology of Costa's minimal surface puncturing the torus be written in a similar fashion, for example in dimension 3?
I was thinking it could be as simple as $S^{1}\times S^{1}\times S^{1}$???